# Pass value of input to other input without onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, onload

I have a working code to pass value from one id to another, but to do that I need a button to pass it onclick. I want to pass the value without a button directly to the other input.
As I did my research i just saw onclick solutions..
Is there any other way or am I stuck with this option

My Code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('email2').value = document.getElementById('email').value;
        document.getElementById('firma2').value = document.getElementById('firma').value;
        document.getElementById('name2').value = document.getElementById('name').value;
        document.getElementById('nummer2').value = document.getElementById('nummer').value;

    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:

```js
const textInput = document.querySelector('#text');
const checkboxInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=checkbox]');
const secondInput = document.querySelector('#second');
const thirdInput = document.querySelector('#third');

textInput.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  secondInput.value = e.target.value;
})

textInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  thirdInput.value = e.target.value;
})

const checkboxesSet = new Set();

checkboxInputs.forEach(checkboxInput =>
  checkboxInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const label = document.querySelector(`label[for=${e.target.id}]`).innerText;
    
    checkboxesSet[e.target.checked ? 'add' : 'delete'](label);
    
    const text = [...checkboxesSet].join(', ');

    secondInput.value = text;
    thirdInput.value = text;
  })
)
```

```html
<label for="text">Text input</label>
<input id="text">
<br/>
<label for="checkbox1">Checkbox input 1</label>
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
<br/>
<label for="checkbox2">Checkbox input 2</label>
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
<br/>
<label for="second">While typing</label>
<input id="second">
<br/>
<label for="third">At the end</label>
<input id="third">
```

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. thank you very much, will mark it as the solution when stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: under which function can i put that ? windows.onload wont let me be able to post the values ? it puts the values in the input field but cant read the values when i pass them

Comment: @nanchalantflow You can use [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: not working...:(

Comment: @nanchalantflow What is the error?

Comment: @nanchalantflow You can also just include your JS file at the bottom of HTML file and don't wait full render manually

Comment: the issue was with one input field. it had nothing to do with the js, my fault.. thanks for your help

Comment: is it possible to do your solution with value="" or label to input ? I have this Code: https://pastebin.com/tP4q12vL which is a checkbox, that I want to paste exactly like you did above but with the value or the label auf the checkbox when its checked.

Comment: @nanchalantflow Sorry but I can not understand what you want exactly. You want to change label of checkbox only if checkbox checked or you mean something else? You can also ask another question and give more examples and information

Comment: I want to pass the label of a checked checkbox to a input textfield without onclick, just like your solution.

Comment: @nanchalantflow Check updated answer

Comment: That is a good solution, but how I turn it otherwise ? Because I have 8 checkbox for one input field, you can change multiple input fields with one checkbox i want to change one input field with multiple checkboxes.

Comment: @nanchalantflow Add same event listener to your other checkboxes

Comment: well that was easier than I expected it to be.. thank you very much, just need to find out how to not replace the value in the input field when more checkboxes are checked, because i want to add them to eachother so a user can have multiple options to pass to the input field

Comment: @nanchalantflow Check new solution

Comment: You my friend, you are the best. Thats a perfect solution it works very good. i love u

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using onchange instead of onclick.